# How to get content-length from a file URL?

Tags: python-3.x, request

I want to extract the content-length from a file URL using request but I'm unable to do so without downloading the file. I have used `requests.get` and `requests.head`.

```
url = 'http://www.example.com'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.head(url)
filename = r.headers
print(filename)
```

The response is

```
{'Date': 'Tue, 07 Aug 2018 15:19:05 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': '__cfduid=d3f062f59c1c1c8a1c492c86ad4b139451533655145; expires=Wed, 07-Aug-19 15:19:05 GMT; path=/; domain=.apkmonk.com; HttpOnly', 'Vary': 'Origin', 'X-Amz-Request-Id': '1548A33AA7546D9A', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '446ab830e3348963-MAA', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

With `requestss.get` it start downloading first.

Comment: Can you show us your latest attempt?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51731349/edit). Don't post code in comments. It's unreadable in comments.

Comment: with requestss.get it start downloading first

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51731349/edit). Don't post code in comments. It's unreadable in comments.

Comment: Please edit your post. You need to redact some sensitive stuff or at least obfuscate it man. Please...